# composer autoload с windows на linux

Tags: composer

Скрипт написан был под виндой, на php, при запуске через командную строку на windows 7 скрипт запускается.

При переносе на linux и запуске выдает ошибку, что якобы класс не найден. Используется composer для автозагрузки.

Пример `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require" : {
        "cboden/ratchet" : "=v0.3.4",
        "zendframework/zend-serializer" : "=2.6.1",
        "zendframework/zend-validator" : "=2.5.3",
        "zendframework/zend-filter" : "=2.6.1",
        "defiant/randomorg" : "=dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "dev",
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Daemon\\" : "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на регистр букв в namespace и названий директорий, т.к. для windows путь DaeMon/ClAAsS == Daemon/Claass, а вот для linux'а это совершенно разные пути